# What are some real world examples of nearly sorted lists

Tags: algorithms, sorting

I found that sorting algorithms such as Insertion Sort and Djikstra's Smoothsort approach O(n) complexity when the list is nearly sorted. What are some real world scenarios where a list is nearly sorted?

Comment: Consider a collection of items which is constantly being modified slightly such that the relative ordering only changes slowly over time. Can you think of a real-world example of that?

Comment: A sorted list, to which you have appended a few new elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about log files described in [AWStats logfile analyzer 7.5 Documentation](http://www.awstats.org/docs/awstats_faq.html)?

> An error log file is not always completely sorted but only "nearly" sorted because of cache and writing log engines used by a server.